# How to encrypt all existing views in SQL Server 2005 after it has been created?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to encrypt all existing views in SQL Server 2005?

I can encrypt them while creating it WITH ENCRYPTION clause but do not know how to do it after creating it.

Comment: duplicate of your previously closed question.

Comment: @mitch so what? I will go on asking it till you guys throw me out. If you think I am harming the cause what SO is all about, then be it. Internet will decide your fate. Big guys also lose.

Comment: Can down voters comment please?

Comment: Weird guys. Cannot understand why it is not a real question. SQL Server allows encrypting views but only allows when creating them and all that I wanted to know how to do it if you had already created them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recreate all the views WITH ENCRYPTION,

**BUT**

notice - that it is *very* weak protection and actually works well only against "honest people"

**SO**

you cannot encrypt the views and SPs in sql server with appropriate level of security, try to manage the access to sql server instead - look to `VIEW DEFINITION` and similar permissions